Is it possible to make a dynamic answer using imageCropAspectRatio, on filament?
I'm encountering an issue with Filament. I want to crop the image based on the orientation that the category has in the database. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to do this. I'm new to using the Filament framework. If any of you have developed something similar before, could you please help me? Here is a snippet of my code:
public static function categoryState(int $state): ?string
    {
        $category = Category::find($state);
        
        // foreach ($category as $descendant) {
            if($category->id == $state){
            if ($category->image_position == 'horizontal') {
                return '16:9';
            }
            if ($category->image_position == 'vertical') {
                return '1:1';
            }
            // if ($category){ return $category->image_position == 'horizontal'? '16:9' : '1:1';}
            }
    
        // }
    }

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\Select::make('category_id')
                    ->label('Categoria')
                    ->relationship('category', 'name')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->live(onBlur: true)
                    ->preload()
                    ->reactive(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                    ->label('Nome')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('link')
                    ->label('Link')
                    ->required()
                    ->url()
                    ->maxLength(255)
                    ->columnSpanFull(),
                Forms\Components\Hidden::make('image_position'),
                Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('image')
                    ->label('Imagem')
                    ->required()
                    ->image()
                    ->imageEditor()
                    ->imageEditorMode(2)
                    ->directory('projects')
                    ->live(onBlur: true)
                    ->imageCropAspectRatio(fn(Get $get) => self::categoryState($get('category_id'))),
                Forms\Components\ToggleButtons::make('featured')
                    ->label('Mostrar na home')
                    ->inline()
                    ->boolean()
                    ->columnSpanFull(),
            ]);
    }

I tried to use parallel functions, but the only options I got were 16:9 or 1:1. I think they are conflicting with each other, but I don't know how to fix it.
